# Convert whole dataframe from lower case to upper case with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, type-conversion, uppercase, lowercase

I have a dataframe like the one displayed below:

```
# Create an example dataframe about a fictional army
raw_data = {'regiment': ['Nighthawks', 'Nighthawks', 'Nighthawks', 'Nighthawks'],
            'company': ['1st', '1st', '2nd', '2nd'],
            'deaths': ['kkk', 52, '25', 616],
            'battles': [5, '42', 2, 2],
            'size': ['l', 'll', 'l', 'm']}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['regiment', 'company', 'deaths', 'battles', 'size'])
```

[image]

My goal is to transform every single string inside of the dataframe to upper case so that it looks like this:

[image]

Notice: all data types are objects and must not be changed; the output must contain all objects. I want to avoid to convert every single column one by one... I would like to do it generally over the whole dataframe possibly.

What I tried so far is to do this but without success

```
df.str.upper()
```

Comment: `str` only works for series...

Answer (score 84, accepted):

[astype()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) will cast each series to the [dtype](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#astype) object (string) and then call the [str()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.Series.str.html#pandas.Series.str) method on the converted series to get the string literally and call the function [upper()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.upper) on it. Note that after this, the dtype of all columns changes to object.

```
In [17]: df
Out[17]: 
     regiment company deaths battles size
0  Nighthawks     1st    kkk       5    l
1  Nighthawks     1st     52      42   ll
2  Nighthawks     2nd     25       2    l
3  Nighthawks     2nd    616       2    m

In [18]: df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.upper())
Out[18]: 
     regiment company deaths battles size
0  NIGHTHAWKS     1ST    KKK       5    L
1  NIGHTHAWKS     1ST     52      42   LL
2  NIGHTHAWKS     2ND     25       2    L
3  NIGHTHAWKS     2ND    616       2    M
```

You can later convert the 'battles' column to numeric again, using [to_numeric()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html#pandas.to_numeric):

```
In [42]: df2 = df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.upper())

In [43]: df2['battles'] = pd.to_numeric(df2['battles'])

In [44]: df2
Out[44]: 
     regiment company deaths  battles size
0  NIGHTHAWKS     1ST    KKK        5    L
1  NIGHTHAWKS     1ST     52       42   LL
2  NIGHTHAWKS     2ND     25        2    L
3  NIGHTHAWKS     2ND    616        2    M

In [45]: df2.dtypes
Out[45]: 
regiment    object
company     object
deaths      object
battles      int64
size        object
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 71):

This can be solved by the following [`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) method:

```
df = df.applymap(lambda s: s.lower() if type(s) == str else s)
```

Answer (score 16):

Loops are very slow instead of using apply function to each and cell in a row, try to get columns names in a list and then loop over list of columns to convert each column text to lowercase.

Code below is the vector operation which is faster than apply function.

```
for columns in dataset.columns:
    dataset[columns] = dataset[columns].str.lower()
```

Comment: Nice
``def m3(dataset):
    for columns in dataset.columns:
        dataset[columns] = dataset[columns].str.upper() 
    return dataset

%timeit pd.concat([df[col].astype(str).str.upper() for col in df.columns], axis=1)
%timeit df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.upper())
%timeit m3(df)
``
70.5 ms ± 1.26 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
82.1 ms ± 1.46 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
40.8 ms ± 546 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

Answer (score 9):

Since `str` only works for series, you can apply it to each column individually then concatenate:

```
In [6]: pd.concat([df[col].astype(str).str.upper() for col in df.columns], axis=1)
Out[6]: 
     regiment company deaths battles size
0  NIGHTHAWKS     1ST    KKK       5    L
1  NIGHTHAWKS     1ST     52      42   LL
2  NIGHTHAWKS     2ND     25       2    L
3  NIGHTHAWKS     2ND    616       2    M
```

---

Edit: **performance comparison**

```
In [10]: %timeit df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.upper())
100 loops, best of 3: 3.32 ms per loop

In [11]: %timeit pd.concat([df[col].astype(str).str.upper() for col in df.columns], axis=1)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.32 ms per loop
```

Both answers perform equally on a small dataframe.

```
In [15]: df = pd.concat(10000 * [df])

In [16]: %timeit pd.concat([df[col].astype(str).str.upper() for col in df.columns], axis=1)
10 loops, best of 3: 104 ms per loop

In [17]: %timeit df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.upper())
10 loops, best of 3: 130 ms per loop
```

On a large dataframe my answer is slightly faster.

Answer (score 7):

try this

```
df2 = df2.apply(lambda x: x.str.upper() if x.dtype == "object" else x)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to conserve the dtype use `isinstance(obj,type)`

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.str.upper().str.strip() if isinstance(x, object) else x)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want conserv dtype or change only one type.. try for and if:

```
for x in dados.columns:
    if dados[x].dtype == 'object':
        print('object - allow upper')
        dados[x] = dados[x].str.upper()
    else:
        print('other? - not allow upper')
        dados[x] = dados[x].str.upper()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please check your answer as the `not allow upper` in the else part is doing `upper` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply it for every cols...

oh_df.columns = map(str.lower, oh_df.columns)