# Convert entire data frame lower case & remove nan, python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have tried to convert entire data frame to lowercase using below script. But blank will fill with nan, I tried to remove nan by but no use.

```
data = data.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.lower())
data = data.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)
```

How to solve this?

Comment: This should work if you make `regex=False`

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39512002/convert-whole-dataframe-from-lower-case-to-upper-case-with-pandas

Comment: @Zero, there was issue as blank filling nan, so I asked in new thread

Comment: @faithon.gvr.py Q1+Q2 is still a duplicate. Both these are answered as separate questions already. See for NaN https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26837998/pandas-replace-nan-with-blank-empty-string

Comment: @Zero, OK fine. I agree...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are close - first [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html), then [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) and last convert to `lowercase`:

```
data = data.fillna('').astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.lower())
```