# Convert multiple dataframes in lower case

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to put all the dataframes' rows in lower case. I am considering multiple dataframes, so I am doing a for loop through them. 
I have tried as follows

```
for i, file in enumerate(files):
        df[str(i)]= pd.read_csv(file)
        df[str(i)].apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.lower())
```

but unfortunately it is not returning rows in lower case. 
I have follower the answer given in a previous post: [Convert whole dataframe from lower case to upper case with Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39512002/convert-whole-dataframe-from-lower-case-to-upper-case-with-pandas)

Could you please tell me what it is wrong in the code above? Thanks

Comment: Thank you to both so much. Both answers were correct. Yes, you're right! I forgot to save the changes, so without assigning the changes were not applied and showed anywhere.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad you understood what was happening wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're putting your DataFrames into a dictionary; that definitely helps.
But you have to assign the result of the `.apply()` operation to something.
As it is it's not being saved anywhere.
Try instead (with `df` renamed to be more clear):

```
df_dict = {}
for i, f in enumerate(files):
    df_dict[str(i)] = pd.read_csv(f)
    df_dict[str(i)] = df_dict[str(i)].apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.lower())
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to use it this way:

```
df[str(i)] = df[str(i)].apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.lower())
```

Answer (score 0):

It is more "clean" (and quicker) approach to operate **only** on *string* columns.

*Pandas* has *select_dtypes* method, where you can pass *include='object'*
parameter, to get columns of *object* type (actually *string*).

But application of your lambda function to such a DataFrame (result of
*select_dtypes*) alone only **generates** the lower-cased content, but
does not save it anywhere.

So to convert the columns in question you should run *update* with the
result of both these functions (*select_dtypes* and *apply*):

```
df.update(df.select_dtypes(include='object')\
    .apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.lower()))
```

And as I suppose, after that you should save the current DataFrame back
to the source file.